# Commutativity of reals using Cauchy seq.

Tags: analysis, cauchy-sequences

I am trying to prove that real numbers are commutative using the definition of real numbers as the equivalence class of Cauchy sequences of rational numbers.

The following is what I know and what I plan.

> RTP If $x,y \in \Bbb R$, then $x+y = y+x$ and $xy = yx$.
>
> My understanding is that if $x \in \Bbb R$ it means that $x$ is the equivalence class of the rational sequence $\{x_j\}$.
>
> Since rationals are commutative, it's clear that $\{x_j+y_j\} \equiv \{y_j +x_j\}$ so I am planning to use this idea with multiplication as well.

Now this is my question.

Do I have to show not only the sequence which the terms are switched, but also all the equivalent sequences, as in

> RTP If $\{x_j\} \equiv \{x'_j\}$ and $\{y_j\} \equiv \{y'_j\}$ then $\{x_j+y_j\} \equiv \{y'_j+x'_j\}$ and something analogous to this with multiplication ?

I know how to prove it, I just need advice if this part is actually necessary or if I am missing more.

Comment: Another way to show this is to use the definition of the reals which defines the real numbers as cuts in the rational number system. The ideas are the same (most properties for $\mathbb R$ are inherited from $\mathbb Q$, such as commutativity of addition/multiplication) but there are no equivalence relations/sequences involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the argument in the second box if you've already shown that addition and multiplication of Cauchy sequences is well-defined on equivalence classes. Once you've shown that, it suffices to work with any arbitrary choice of representatives. (Because the operations being well-defined on equivalences classes means precisely that you can pick any pair representatives, add them, and all the resulting sequences will be in the same equivalence class.)

I assume you showed addition and multiplication were well-defined when they were first introduced, so you probably don't need the second argument.

Comment: Thank you very much. It makes a lot better sense. Long story short, I just need to show that commutativity works with arbitrary sequence that are equivalent, right ?

And it does because the sequences are rational.

Comment: @hyg17 What exactly do you mean by that? Here is how I would describe the argument: You want to show $a+b=b+a$ for real numbers $a$ and $b$. Since real numbers are equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences, and addition is well-defined (choice of representative doesn't matter), it suffices to pick a sequence representing $a$, a sequence representing $b$, and show that the addition of these sequences commutes. But this is clear. You get the same sequence regardless of the order you add them because you know addition of rationals commutes.

Comment: @hyg17 (So I think the answer to your question is yes.)

Answer (score 1):

It is true that the real numbers can be shown to be equal as the limit of Cauchy sequences of rationals under the equivalence class, but have you ever thought about the fact that you need the real numbers to construct metric spaces, hence to define Cauchy sequences themselves?

It can be done, but one must take care not to use the general theory of metric spaces (which builds itself on the existence of $\mathbb R$) and do all the work by hand assuming all distances worked with are rational distances.

As long as you show that with the definition $\{x_i\} + \{y_i\} \overset{def}= \{ x_i + y_i \}$, you have $\{x_i\} + \{ y_i \} = \{ y_i \} + \{ x_i \}$, you are okay. Both expressions on each side do not depend on the choice of representatives of their respective equivalence classes, so showing it only for one choice of representatives is enough. Same comments for multiplication. The issue you are worried with is that *addition is well-defined*, and it is a different concern.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thank you ! I'm still a bit iffy about what it means to be "well defined". lol

Comment: @hyg17 : It means that when I write 
$$
\{ x_i \} + \{ y_i \} \overset{def}= \{ x_i + y_i\},
$$
this definition used the explicit representative "sequence $(x_i)$ and $(y_i)$" to define the sum, but I could've used other representatives. Being well defined means that if $\{x_i\} = \{x_i'\}$ and similarly for $y$, then the identity
$$
\{x_i' + y_i'\} = \{x_i'\} + \{y_i'\} = \{x_i\} + \{y_i\} = \{x_i + y_i\}
$$
holds. (Note that the two equalities at both ends are not actual equalities, they are *definitions* ; so if we choose wrong definitions and those two things end up being different...

Comment: we are in trouble, the sum is not "well-defined". You don't want problems such as $a+b \neq a'+b'$ when $a=a'$ and $b=b'$! (don't forget that $a=a'$ can be something 'non-trivial', i.e. $a$ and $a'$ don't have to be written exactly the same, you can use different representative of the equivalence class of $a$ to write $a$)!)